# How can I parameterise my Haskell functions?

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, monads, state-monad

I hope my terminology is correct here - if not, feel free to edit anything.

I'm using Haskell as a helper-language whilst writing a paper on combinatorial game theory - i.e., all of my functions just juggle numbers and help me to come to a solution for the game I'm studying.

I wrote all of the functions for a concrete, integral 'board size' (think chequerboard, 5x5 etc). I wanted to expand to study boards of any size, so modified all the relevant functions by including an Integer parameter. *e.g.*,

```
type Size = Int

squares :: Size -> [Square]
squares size = [ (x,y) | x <- [1..size],  
                         y <- [1..size]]
```

This, however, has started to get messy. Functions which normally I would consider size-independent have to be supplied with a Size whenever they access a function which requires a Size.

This very quickly leads to lines like this:

```
reaching size = (losing size) \\\ (setA size)

takeUDmir _  []       = []
takeUDmir size (x:xs) = [x] ++ takeUDmir size (xs \\\ mirUD size x)

rotate size s = concatMap (mirUD size) (mirLR size s)
```

(Note that the content of the functions really doesn't matter, I'm just trying to show how out-of-hand it has become.)

I'm pretty confident using Haskell, and with functional programming in general, but I've got no idea how I could go about removing all of these `size` references, and simply relying on something else which sets the size for each function which requires its use.

I think I'm probably looking for a monad, but I've got no idea.

Comment: Maybe you just need to define all your functions in a where clause where size is bound?

Comment: @augustss: that occurred to me, but I figured there would be a more elegant way of going about it.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies and comments - there were more ways of going about this than I might have expected. Hopefully this answer can help someone else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a perfect time to pull out the `Reader` monad—it abstracts the notion of some globally available, read-only configuration data.

```
data Config = Config { size :: Int, ... }

type MyMonad = Reader Config

fun :: MyMonad Result
fun = funNeedingTheSize <$> asks size <*> pure arg1 <*> pure arg2

runMyMonad :: Config -> MyMonad a -> a
runMyMonad = flip runReader
```

Comment: 10/10 for Reader monad using Applicative syntax. Mmmm.

Comment: Thanks! It seems indeed that's what I'm looking for. I understand the concept of monads, but I expect it'll take me a while to actually work out how to rewrite my functions in the appropriate style.

Comment: Start with all of the functions which actually use the `size`. These will have to be rewritten to use `ask` (or `asks` if you use the `Config` data structure style as I used above) and thus will become wrapped in your `Reader` monad structure. If there are many layers of non-size-dependent computation "above" those functions then it can be layered on with `fmap` and if there are places where you must combine multiple "impure" (size-dependent) computations you can use monadic or applicative style combinators.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to flesh out Augustss' suggestion here. If you just need to define `size` once then  you could build all of the dependent machinery in a local binding. This effectively lets you create a number of functions all inside the context of a specific definition of `size` and then later use all of these functions just picking the `size` once. It goes especially well with `RecordWildCards`

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards -#}

data Methods =
  Methods { meth1 :: Int -> Int
          , meth2 :: Int -> Int
          ...
          }

mkMethods :: Int -- ^ size
          -> Methods
mkMethods size = 
  Methods { meth1 = \i -> size + i
          , meth2 = \i -> size - i
          ...
          }

...

someFn :: Int -> Result
someFn size = ... meth1 ... meth2 ...
  where Methods {..} = mkMethods size
```

This is effectively a limited way to simulate ML modules.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the Reader monad is [Implicit Parameters](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=implicit%20parameters#implicit-parameters).

These often get a bad press as the semantics can be subtle if you try to change the value of the parameter in a recursive call.

However they do have the advantage of avoiding the need to rewrite your code in monadic style, which is quite an invasive change that detracts from readability.

My view is that they are perfect in situations like yours where they will just be set once as sort of "configuration" information at the top-level of a chain of calls and not changed inside that chain.

They do still invade your type signatures if you have any, but will be inferred automatically like type classes if you don't give signatures.

Your code snippets above would look like this with implicit parameters if you use them for `size` everywhere:

```
type Size = Int

squares :: (?size :: Size) => [Square]
squares = [ (x,y) | x <- [1..?size],  
                    y <- [1..?size]]

reaching = losing \\\ setA

takeUDmir []     = []
takeUDmir (x:xs) = [x] ++ takeUDmir (xs \\\ mirUD x)

rotate s = concatMap mirUD (mirLR s)
```

It may be that in some of the functions, it's more appropriate to pass the value explicitly - it depends on how significant the `size` parameter is to that particular function.

To actually "instantiate" the parameter, use `let`:

```
let ?size = 5 in squares
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this problem is to use the [`reflection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) library. This is definitely a sophisticated method and should be used with great care. There's a tutorial resource on it by Austin Seipp [available at FP Complete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection) that goes into its implementation, but that can be quite hairy.

The simplified form of `reflection` is the `Given` typeclass. To do that, we simply annotate our functions with `given` wherever we desire some global configured value.

```
meth1 = 1 + given
meth2 = given - 1
```

Like `ImplicitParams` we get notice of our use of `Given` in the type signatures.

```
meth1 :: (Num a, Given a) => a
meth2 :: (Num a, Given a) => a
```

This allows us to statically eliminate them and ensure that all proper configuration information has been passed using `give`

```
give :: a -> (Given a => r) -> r
```

So that if we have `someComplexCalculation :: Given Config => Result` we can solve that by providing a `Config`.

```
give config someComplexCalculation :: Result
```

and the types ensure that we didn't let this missing configuration propagate to the top.

---

The `Reifies`/`reflect`/`reify` machinery generalizes this property, but does so at a loss of some convenience and simplicity. It's needed if you must pass multiple configurations which overlap—using `Given` it'd be impossible for the system to know which `given`s should be replaced by the passed configuration under the overlapping region, `Reifies` solves that with an `s` parameter much like the `ST` monad's `s` parameter.

The killer application for `Reifies` however is passing runtime configured typeclasses to expressions. Normally you can't override typeclasses, but `Reifies` gives a trick way of doing that. See Austin Seipp's tutorial toward the bottom for more details about that.

Comment: You can write something with the signature of `give` for implicit parameters too - is there some way the result can still be subverted?
`give :: a -> ((?given :: a) => r) -> r ; 
give v c = let ?given = v in c`

Comment: Hm, you're correct. I misunderstood how implicit params were working. I'll adjust the comparison points.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Do you think implicit parameters can be used everywhere one would otherwise use the reflection library? (Are they solving the same problem?) If so, that would be quite a nice observation, I think.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Section 6.2 of [Oleg and Ken Shan's paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/tr-15-04.pdf) has a detailed comparison; my reading is that they think they both solve the same problem but that implicit parameters are dangerous for other reasons.